# Creating a joined array column from another array column - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array column called `fields` in table `tt_test` as follows:

```
fields
{A}
{B,C}
{D}
{E}
```

Table `tt_config` contains a `field_id` for each `field`:

```
field   field_id
A          1
B          2
C          3
D          4
E          5
```

From the two tables above, I need to create a third called `tt_output`

```
fields    field_ids
{A}          {1}
{B,C}       {2,3}
{D}          {4}
{E}          {5}
```

Fairly new to postgresql/sql so any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a scalar sub-query:

```
select t.fields, 
       array(select c.field_id
             from tt_config c
             where c.field = any(t.fields)) as field_ids
from tt_test t
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the "any" function was the key here, I tried something similar with the "IN" operator but that selected field_ids as a list of all fields that every occur in tt_test:

Comment: This was my incorrect approach: 
select A.fields,
       C.field_ids
from TT_TEST A
INNER JOIN ( 
 select ARRAY_AGG(B.field_id) as field_ids
   from tt_config B
  where B.field IN (select UNNEST(fields) from TT_TEST)
) C on true

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` operator to join to tables.
to use this operator it's necessary to have two identical headers.

You can use this query

```sql
select fields , null as field_ids from tt_test
union
select fields , field_ids from tt_config
```